# Change transition to ONE ViewController in a UINavigationController while keeping back-swipe

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uikit

I'd like to implement a custom transition to ONE specific view-controller inside my UINavigationController.

I can do so by providing my custom TransitionAnimator inside

```
func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, animationControllerFor operation: UINavigationController.Operation, from fromVC: UIViewController, to toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning?
```

or return nil otherwise and everything works fine! So the animation part is solved and working!

BUT by returning nil for the times I want the default transition, I loose the back-swipe gesture.

So my question is:
How can I provide my custom transition to one specific VC, but keep everything else as is?!?

Comment: Can you share what the transition looks like in gif/video?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to subclass UINavigationController and manage interactivePopGestureRecognizer on your own.

```
class CustomNavController: UINavigationController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self
    }
}

extension CustomNavController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        if gestureRecognizer === interactivePopGestureRecognizer {
            return viewControllers.count > 1
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make the view controller the navigation delegate and then reset it back to nil. like:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self
}

override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = nil
}
```

Then perform your custom animation in the view controller or make an object/class to handle it for you